# Подгрузка атласов с текстурами в libgdx занимает очень много времени

Tags: разработка-игр, libgdx

По мере написания приложения, появлялось все больше и больше картинок, я расфасовал их по атласам и их получилось порядка 20 штук. Решил воспользоваться классом AssetManager, в результате все ресурсы загружаются при старте, но довольно долго для простенькой 2д игры от 10 до 20 секунд в среднем. Но что то мне подсказывает что, я делаю что то неправильно. 
Собственно реализация у меня следующая, может кто-нибудь сможет подсказать какие были допущены ошибки:

```
  public LoadingScreen(final TheBolt app){
        this.app = app;
        app.assets.load("loadbg/Loading.png", Texture.class);
        app.assets.finishLoading();
        stage = new Stage(new FillViewport(MobileVars.SCR_WIDTH, MobileVars.SCR_HEIGHT));

        instance = Singleton.getInstance();

        Texture texture = app.assets.get("loadbg/Loading.png", Texture.class);

        splash = new Image(texture);
        splash.setSize(MobileVars.SCR_WIDTH, MobileVars.SCR_HEIGHT);
        splash.setOrigin(0, 0);

        stage.addActor(splash);
    }

    private void queueAssets() {
        app.assets.load("About/About.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("AboutScreen/aboutScreen.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("bg/background.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("LooseButtons/LooseButtons.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("MainButtons/MenuButtons.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("Office/office.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("BgOffice/BgOffice.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("Player/Player.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("Player/PlayerWomen.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("Bolts/Bolts.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("BoltOffice/BoltOffice.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("PlayerOffice/PlayerOffice.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("Ventilate/VentAtlas.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("Bolts/health.png", Texture.class);
        app.assets.load("MainButtons/Pause.png", Texture.class);
        app.assets.load("MainButtons/Play.png", Texture.class);

        app.assets.load("printer/printer.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("playerRotation/playerRotation.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("playerRotation/WomanRotation.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("playerAnim/playerAnim.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("playerAnim/womanAnim.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("culer/culer.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
        app.assets.load("Dick/dick.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
    }

 @Override
    public void show() {
        camera = app.getCamera();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        queueAssets();

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        update(delta);

        stage.act(delta);

        stage.draw();


    }

    private void update(float delta) {
        if (app.assets.update()){
            app.fonRender = new FonRender(app);
            buttons = new Buttons(app);

            officeSetting = new OfficeSetting(app);
            app.setScreen(new MainScreen(app));
        }
    }
```

Comment: можно попробовать атласы не в png, а в etc1 загружать. Загрузка происходит значительно быстрее (раз в 10 быстрее текстура etc1 загружается, по сравнению с png на мобилках). Но как это делается в libgdx надо разбираться.

Answer (score 1):

У вас же 23 атласа. Мне кажется, вы концепцию атласов не понимаете...

Я не знаю, как нынче дела обстоят, но когда я работал с LibGDX (в частности, можете посмотреть [мою статью про атласы](http://suvitruf.ru/2012/10/28/2401/)), то делал всего 1 атлас и разбивал на регионы. Не думаю, что с тех пор что-то поменялось. Вам рекомендую сделать тоже самое.

Что-то вроде:

```
private void loadTextures() {
  //создание текстуры
  texture  = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/atlas.png"));

  //Получение регионов. Атлас у нас состоит из 4 изображений одинакового размера. 
  //Так что выцепить отдельные регионы не составляет проблемы.
  TextureRegion tmp[][] = TextureRegion.split(texture, texture.getWidth() / 4, texture.getHeight() / 4);

  //добавляем в массив регионов
  textureRegions.put("player", tmp[0][0]);
  textureRegions.put("brick1", tmp[0][1]);
  textureRegions.put("brick2", tmp[1][0]);
  textureRegions.put("brick3", tmp[1][1]);
}
```

Comment: так получилось что некоторые из них с разрешением 4096x4096 и я постеснялся сделать один огромный со всеми изображениями. За статью спасибо

Comment: @NikitaAkulov зависит от target sdk API. На многих старых телефонах максимальный размер атласа 1024x1024 (:

Comment: Так как мне тогда выйти из ситуации? Получается мне все равно придется делать несколько атласов для такого количества изображений?

Comment: @NikitaAkulov а вы как пакуете атласы?

Comment: через texture packer.

Comment: просто мне кажется, что я либо неправильно упаковал, либо не правильно загружаю при старте приложения, а скорее всего и то и то вместе.